# laravel - sending mail doesn't work

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4, mandrill

I am using Mandrill and there is no error message and no email sent

mail.php

```
<?php

return array(

    'driver' => 'smtp',

    'host' => 'smtp.mandrillapp.com',

    'port' => 587,

    'from' => array('address' => "my-email@gmail.com", 'name' => null),

    'username' => 'my-email@gmail.com',

    'password' => 'api key',

);
```

using email function (confide package)

```
 Mail::queueOn(
                Config::get('confide::email_queue'),
                Config::get('confide::email_account_confirmation'),
                compact('user'),
                function ($message) use ($user) {
                    $message
                        ->from('my-email@gmail.com', 'Test')
                        ->to($user->email, $user->username)
                        ->subject(Lang::get('confide::confide.email.account_confirmation.subject'));
                }
            );
```

Comment: never used mandrill with laravel only mailtrap but try to change the port to 25 and encryption to ''

Comment: mandrill uses port 587, i tried to use Gmail directly but it doesn't work

Comment: can you post the full code of the email function you are using? your configs seems to be fine.

Comment: Are there any errors in your laravel.log?

Comment: do you release the queue? like php artisan queue:listen and do you have the queue dependency that you are using installed?

Comment: @michael
[2015-01-21 22:51:27] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Insufficient data for unserializing - 1465 required, 264 present' in /home/moamen/taskat/my-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php:253

Comment: Are you using beanstalked for queueing? Is you application key in config/app.php something like 'Your secret key'? @MoamenAbdelwahed

Comment: @michael i found "pda/pheanstalk": "~2.1" in composer.lock, is it ?

Comment: pheanstalk is the component you need to run beanstalked queues, so it might be that you were using beanstalked (or have installed pheanstalkd earlier). What's in your config/queue.php? Which queue driver is listed there?

Comment: @michael `'default' => 'sync','connections' => array(

  'sync' => array(
   'driver' => 'sync',
  ),

  'beanstalkd' => array(
   'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
   'host'   => 'localhost',
   'queue'  => 'default',
   'ttr'    => 60,
  ), ...
 )`

Comment: You can try it, but I don't think it will work. Go to your laravel dir and run php artisan queue:work and see if something is send. But you don't have a queue service installed, so the queueOn option won't work usually. You can try to send emails via Mail::send command, if you want to make use of queue, add a queue service like beanstalked. Here's a great howto: [LARACASTS](https://laracasts.com/lessons/beanstalkd-queues-with-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure `'pretend' => false` and the rest of the configuration looks fine.

This is an example for sending mail:

```
$attributes=array('firstname'=>"John", 'email'=>$email);
Mail::send('page_to_be_sent',$attributes,function($message){
                $message->to($email)->subject('Your subject here.');
           });
```